# Is it mandatory for the bride to pierce her nose for marriage in Islam?

Tags: nikah, islamic-basis

This is creating a difficult situation for me. My parent and relative asked me to do this but the bride doesn't want to.

Is it mandatory for the bride to pierce her nose for wearing jewelry (nose ring), for marriage in Islam?.

Comment: It is not - and I have to say, I have never heard of this custom. Interesting!

Answer (score 5):

**Nope it is not**. It might be a tradition in some regions, but apart from that it has nothing to do with Islamic marriages.

The only things that are must are,

**Consent** – Both the groom and the bride must consent to the marriage, verbally and in writing. `Wali comes into this category on behalf of bride to do the consent`

**Mahr**

**Witnesses**

**Prenuptial Contract Conditions** – Either the bride or the groom may submit contract conditions which, if agreed upon, become legally-binding conditions of marriage.

Comment: You mean, there is nothing according to hadish. right?

Comment: Yup, neither Hadeeths nor Al Quran said to pierce bride's nose. It is only a traditional trend in some regions.

Comment: The same goes for ears' piercing. Almost all women in the world do it, so these things are more of culture, tradition or fashion following.

Comment: Actually bride's consent is mandatory - the "wali" cannot consent on behalf of the bride.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is no more than a tradition and is not connected to Islam.

**Mandatory things For Marriage are:**

**1.Mutual consent of spouse**

**2.Haq Mahr**

**3.Witnesses**

**4.Consent of parents is disputed among Islamic Schools of thought**

**5.Conditions are optional**

Hope you find the answer, Allah bless you and us.

Comment: There is no consent of parents required, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As a Hindu I give my opinion. Islam is not a religion originated in India. Hence the probability of nose ring among muslim women may not be correct as the use of nose ring was abundantly used only by Hindus. Considering the conversion into Islam by Hindus who cannot forget the tradition this might be in practice among the ladies of Islam. Interestingly this habit will be more among the ladies who speak vernacular language and not Urdu

Answer (score 0):

Muslim wedding customs in Indo Pak regions are sometimes identical to Hindu Indian ones other than the Imam doing the Nikah ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

Piercing of nose is a sign that the women has been married (in some customs in India and Pakistan and nearby regions). It is not mandatory. It is taught to publicize that the two person are married. It is encouraged in religion to publicize that a person is married (I am assuming to make other men stay away from the woman). Thus if piercing is halal (I am assuming it is) then perhaps it is a good thing but not mandatory.

Answer (score -3):

To the contrary piercing any body part is prohibited in Islam. Piercing is an exclusively *aboriginal* practice that is prevalent only in India apart from certain primitive and uncivilized societies.

Piercing is also practiced by *Satan Worshiping Heavy Metal Band* and that is adequate proof to its unislamic origin.

Hence Muslims shouldn't pierce their ears and noses.

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. The so called *'Satan Worshiping 'Heavy Metal Band'* breath air and drink water. That doesn't mean breathing and drinking water has 'UnIslamic' origin. Be academic and polite in your answer. Use reference wherever required. Please go through [answer].